Como puedo solucionar el problema de publicacion de mi sitio en django en apache2
Pase mi sitio a producción y me ocurre que no me carga mi archivo wsgi.py y me visualiza el sitio de esta manera.

que pudiera estar pasando el código del virtualhost en apache es el siguiente
<VirtualHost *:80>

#WSGIPythonPath /usr/bin/python3/
WSGIScriptAlias /cosmetic /var/www/html/cosmetic/cosmetic/wsgi.py

Alias /static/ /var/www/html/cosmetic/cosmetic/static/

<Directory /var/www/html/cosmetic/cosmetic/>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>

</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/cosmetic/cosmetic/static/>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

al poner el path de python WSGIPythonPath /usr/bin/python3/ se bloquea el servicio y si elimino la linea el servicio me funciona paro con este problema.
Muchas gracias a quien me pueda ayudar.
